# How was this patent issued over the prior art?

Tags: prior-art, design-patent, usd651568

I don't see a substantial difference between this part and a standard banana jack.  For example - http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70209775.

[image]

Versus [USD651568](http://www.google.com/patents/usd651568)

[image]

The purpose of this part is to act as an insulator around a banana socket.  But these have been around for decades.

How was this patent issued?

Answer (score 2):

This is a **design patent**. Design patents are **not for inventions**, but for a unique look or styling. Relevant prior art would be a female connector that looked like this.